# Multiple variables *with different options* on the same grouped boxplot in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot

I'm a beginner level R user.  I have a dataset of a group of animals and their lead test levels and want to have a visual summary of what factors about the animals mean higher or lower lead levels.  I'd like to make one big boxplot with all of this information broken down and grouped by variables: lead test results for males/females, overweight/normal/underweight, etc, where each variable type is a color, and each option for that variable is its own boxplot.  I can't find example plots doing what I want, just lots of examples of multiple/grouped plots where each variable only has the same options, like male/female or year.  With my data, some variables have two options, some have several.  I'd love to create something like the plot linked, but where each grouped section is for one categorical variable, and each variable has different options.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/m0E19.png

Is this even possible (preferably in ggplot2), or would I need to make a plot for each variable and paste them together in Photoshop?  A similar question seems to have been asked hundreds of times here, but those questions are about datasets where the variables options are all the same.

Comment: Please `dput()` a sample of your data and include the code that you have tried so far.

Comment: There is no code for me to try because nothing yet exists to do what I'm trying to do.  I don't see where I can upload a .csv or other file to share my data.

Answer (score 0):

We can make this `reprex` by mutating the `ggplot2::diamonds` data to approximate the form of your `animals` data.

```
#load dependencies
library(magrittr)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

#create data.frame
animals <- ggplot2::diamonds %>% 
  mutate( lead = price,
          sex = if_else(color <="F","Female","Male"),
          weight = if_else(cut  %in% c("Fair","Good") ,"Underweight",
                                  if_else(cut %in% c("Very Good","Premium"), "Normal Weight", "Overweight")
                          )
         )  %>%  
  select(sex, weight, lead)
```

My method for creating the `boxplot` using `ggplot2` would be first to create a 
new `data.frame` made up of the required summary statistics for each group needed to create your boxplots.  This can be done by running the `get.stats()` function and then using `bind_rows` to combine them:

```
get.stats <- function(group){
  stats <- animals %>% 
  group_by_(group) %>% 
    summarize_(
      min = ~min(lead),
      p25 = ~quantile(lead, .25),            
      mean = ~mean(lead),
      sd = ~sd(lead),
      median = ~median(lead),
      p75 = ~quantile(lead, .75),
      max = ~max(lead),
      n = ~n()
    )



stats <- stats %>%
  mutate(lower = pmax(min, (mean - 1.5*sd)),
         upper = pmin(max, (mean + 1.5*sd)),
         notchlower = pmax(min, median+1.58*(p75-p25)/sqrt(n)),
         notchupper = pmin(max, median-1.58*(p75-p25)/sqrt(n)),
         group.name = group
         ) %>%  
  rename(group.cat = group)
}


#run the function by replacing "sex" and "weight" with the actual variable names of your data

stats.sex <- get.stats("sex")
stats.weight <- get.stats("weight")

stats.all <- bind_rows(stats.sex, stats.weight)
```

Now that the new `data.frame` is created, we can plot with `ggplot2` and `stat = "identity"`

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(stats.all, aes(x = group.cat))+
  geom_boxplot(aes(
    fill = group.name,
    lower = p25,
    notchlower = notchlower,
    upper = p75,
    notchupper = notchupper,
    middle = mean,
    ymin = lower, 
    ymax = upper),
    stat = "identity"
  )+
  facet_wrap(. ~ group.name, scales = "free_x")
```

[image: Plot]

Comment: Thank you for such a detailed reply!  In trying to replicate that myself, something isn't working with the code starting with 

  get.stats <- function(group){  

I'm getting + in my R Studio console and I'm not sure what part of that code might be incomplete

Comment: The get.stats <- function(group){ is creating a function.  That chunk of code must be run all the way through the  end at  rename(group.cat = group)
}  in order to run properly.    Are you running all of those lines at the same time?

Comment: Yes, running the whole thing at once.  The magrittr package is loaded, so it shouldn't be the pipes in the function, and the pipes work in the first bit creating a dataframe.  I'm running R version 3.6.1 in RStudio 1.2.1335.  I also tried running it in just R, and it's also giving me a + sign to indicate something being wrong.  Apologies, I'm not an R expert and don't know how to troubleshoot this.